# creating a mysql connection function in swift 5

Tags: swift

I am new to swift and I can't graps how to transform a normal mysql connection call to a function where I can have a parameter for the pagename in a select query

```
let option = Option(user: "vapor", host: "sql.", port: 3306, password: "", database: "tigerpress")
let pool = ConnectionPool(option: option) // Create a pool with the option
let rows: [Page] = try pool.execute { conn in
    // The connection `conn` is held in this block
    //  try conn.query("SELECT * FROM Pages;")
    try conn.query("SELECT * FROM Pages WHERE name = ' \(pagename)';") // And it returns result to outside execute block
}
```

I need pagename to be the parameter of my function. I did check the manual but I see mostly examples with simple functions returning a string and it doesn't work.

Comment: You mean something  like `func someFunc(pagename: String) -> [String: Any]`? Not sure I understand the question.

Comment: yes! @JoakimDanielson I think so. I basically want to pass a parameter, run the query and return the results